# HQL ManyToMany Query not exists

Tags: many-to-many, hql

I have three tables A, B and A_B (with the @ManyToMany annotation).

I tried to request all A's object that haven't a particulary b.id (:k) with this Query : "Select disctinct a from A a join a.B b where b.id != :k"

But I also want all A's object that haven't an existing b.id and this query above just return A's object that haven't the b.id.

How can i do? Need i use "not exists" on b.id ?

PS: Sorry for my English, it is not my native language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select a from A a where :k not member of a.bs
```

(the k parameter should be an instance of B with the ID to reject)